# Use variable in path, is this possible?

Tags: symfony, variables, twig, symfony-2.8

One question please. I.E, I have this in a twig:

```
<li><a href="{{ path('XXX') }}">XXXLabel</a></li>
```

It's possible create this link from a var? I.E:

```
my_var = XXX
<li><a href="{{ path('my_var') }}">XXXLabel</a></li>
```

I obtain an exception,

> Unable to generate a URL for the named route ....

My objective is to generate a menu from a BD data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TRY this:

```
my_var = XXX
<li><a href="{{ path(my_var) }}">XXXLabel</a></li>
```

Comment: I obtain the same error: An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Unable to generate a URL for the named route "{{ path('XXX') }}" as such route does not exist.").

Comment: because you pass that does not exist route

Comment: The path exist. If I put "{{ path('home') }}" exist. But if "my_var = 'home'" and then I put "{{path(my_var)}}" doesn't generate the route :(

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED.**

It was a data error in my DB. Sorry! and thanks for all!